# Delete 3 of 20 files from a folder at a time through command prompt

Tags: windows, shell, command, command-prompt

c:\users\sam\desktop\test Del x1.txt x2.txt x3.txt

this is working fine.But how to do it without going to path of folder.

Answer (score 0):

you're a little esoteric here... It would be easier to script it.

here is a basic script and you can expand from here:

```
#Get the path
$path = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop"

#Get the files in the path
$Files = Get-ChildItem $path

#Loop through each file
foreach($file in $files)
{
    #Check to see if it's a text file
    if($file -like "*.txt")
    {
        #Delete the file and do not confirm
        Remove-Item $file -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
}
```